# A poem for everyone

Tags: riddle, steganography

> This is for people that hate me, This is for people that love me.
>   I am there from beginning till the end.
>   Mothers serve there sentence for I am the father.
>   Everything breaks under my will.
>
> I cannot be stopped
>
> Yet....

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: how do you accept answers

Comment: There's a greyed-out, circled check-mark below the vote buttons on the answers.  Click on it to turn it green. This marks that answer as your Accepted answer (and awards that answerer some bonus reputation).

Answer (score 5):

> time

I am there from beginning till the end.

...I am the father

> father time

Everything breaks under my will

> erosion, etc. over time everything will be dust

Cannot be stopped. Yet...

> so far, time has not stopped.

Comment: Also notice the first letter of each line

Comment: @frabjrew sneaky

Comment: Great Job @JakenHerman